# Can't receive a JSON object from a php page

Tags: php, android, json

I have a pretty simple php code like this:

```
<?php
$myArr = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");
echo json_encode($myArr);
?>
```

and in my android studio i have the following asynctask class which will result in a string called result:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            result = HttpManager.SendData(dataPack);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            Toast.makeText(c,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mAuthTask = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }
}
```

And the a jsonparser using the result string class as below:

```
private String[] jSonParser(String s){
    String[] mlist={""};
    mlist[0]="no users found";
    if (s != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("types");
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                mlist[i]=a.getString(i);
            }
            Toast.makeText(c, "JSON recieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(c, "JSONException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return mlist;
}
```

But i keep getting the JSONException.what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause, but it might not hurt to set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` via PHP's `header` function.

Comment: can u elaborate plz? U know i even validated my json string and it seems like a basic json string i cant figure out the problem.